# map.panTo does not animate when moving back to the center

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-maps

I have a reactjs app that shows the google map. In the map section, there is a center marker. I also have  button that when clicked, the map should smoothly move back to the center. Now, the button does work, but it does not animate. Kindly help.

The center is from derived coordinates. Also, if anyone knows how I can define the coordinates using the geolocator to get the current location on the map, kindly help.

This is my code

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from 'react';
import { Link, useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import Menubar from "../../components/menubar/Menubar"
import axios from 'axios';
import { UserContext } from "../../UserContext";
import toast, { Toaster } from 'react-hot-toast';
import ActionSheet from "actionsheet-react";
import { useJsApiLoader, GoogleMap, Marker, Autocomplete, DirectionsRenderer } from '@react-google-maps/api'
import Skeleton from 'react-loading-skeleton';


function AddFarm() {

let navigate = useNavigate();
const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
const user = React.useContext(UserContext);
const [show, setShow] = useState(false);

const ref = useRef();
const handleOpen = () => {
    ref.current.open();
};
const handleClose = () => {
    ref.current.close();
}
const center = { lat: -1.1797562, lng: 36.9064927 }

const { isLoaded } = useJsApiLoader({
    googleMapsApiKey: process.env.REACT_APP_GOOGLE_MAPS_API_KEY,
    libraries: ['places'],
})

const [map, setMap] = useState(/** @type google.maps.Map */(null))

if (!isLoaded) {
    return <Skeleton />
}

return (
    <div>
        <Menubar />
        <div className="appHeader bg-primary text-light">
            <div className="left">
                <a onClick={() => navigate(-1)} className="headerButton goBack">
                    <i className="fi fi-rr-angle-left"></i> </a>
            </div>
            <div className="pageTitle">Add Farm</div>
            <div className="right">


            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="appCapsule">

            <div className="section mt-3 mb-3">

                <form onSubmit={submitFarm}>

                    <div className="form-group basic">
                        <div className="input-wrapper">
                            <label className="label" >Name</label>
                            <input type="text" className="form-control" onChange={handleInput} value={farmInput.farmname} name="farmname" placeholder=" Enter farm name" />
                            <i className="clear-input">
                                <i className="fi fi-rr-cross-circle"></i> </i>
                        </div>
                        <div className="invalid-feedback">
                            {errorlist.farmname}
                        </div>
                        <div className="input-info">Give your farm a name</div>
                    </div>

                    <div className="form-group basic">
                        <div className="input-wrapper">
                            <label className="label" >County</label>
                            <select className="form-control custom-select" onChange={handleInput} value={farmInput.county_id} name="county_id">
                                <option value="0">Select County</option>

                                {
                                    county && county.map((item) => {
                                        return (
                                            <option value={item.id} key={item.id}>{item.countyname}</option>
                                        )
                                    })
                                }

                            </select>
                        </div>
                        <div className="invalid-feedback">
                            {errorlist.county_id}
                        </div>
                        <div className="input-info">Enter the county your farm is</div>
                    </div>

                    <div className="form-group basic">
                        <div className="input-wrapper">
                            <label className="label" >Location</label>
                            <input type="text" className="form-control" onChange={handleInput} value={farmInput.farmlocation} name="farmlocation"
                                placeholder="Enter farm location" />
                            <i className="clear-input">
                                <i className="fi fi-rr-cross-circle"></i> </i>
                        </div>
                        <div className="input-info">Enter exactly where you farm is located</div>
                    </div>
                    <div className="mt-2">
                        <button onClick={handleOpen} className="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-lg">Map your Farm</button>

                    </div>

                    <ActionSheet
                        ref={ref}
                        mouseEnable={false}
                        touchEnable={false}
                        sheetStyle={{
                            borderTopLeftRadius: 0,
                            borderTopRightRadius: 0,
                            height: '100%'
                        }}>
                        <div className="appHeader bg-primary text-light">
                            <div className="left">
                                <a onClick={() => setShow(true)} className="headerButton toggle-searchbox">
                                    <i className="fi fi-rr-search"></i> </a>
                            </div>
                            <div className="pageTitle">Map your Farm</div>
                            <div className="right">
                                <a onClick={handleClose} className="headerButton">
                                    <i className="fi fi-rr-cross"></i></a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div id="search" className={show ? "appHeader no-boxshadow show" : "appHeader"}>
                            <div className="search-form">
                                <div className="form-group searchbox">
                                    <input type="text" className="form-control" placeholder="Search..." />
                                    <i className="input-icon">
                                        <i className="fi fi-rr-search"></i> </i>
                                    <a onClick={() => setShow(false)} className="ml-1 close toggle-searchbox">
                                        <i className="fi fi-rr-cross-circle"></i> </a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div className="section full mt-6 h100">
                            <GoogleMap
                                center={center}
                                zoom={18}
                                mapContainerStyle={{ width: '100%', height: '100%' }}
                                options={{
                                    zoomControl: false,
                                    streetViewControl: false,
                                    mapTypeControl: false,
                                    fullscreenControl: false,
                                    mapTypeId: "satellite"
                                }}
                                onLoad={map => setMap(map)}
                            >
                                <Marker position={center} />
                            </GoogleMap>
                            <div class="fab-button animate bottom-right dropdown show bottom-high">
                                <a onClick={() => {
                                    map.panTo(center, { animate: true, duration: 2.0 })
                                    map.setZoom(18)
                                }} class="fab" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="true">
                                    <i class="fi fi-rr-marker"></i>
                                </a>
                            </div>
                            <div className="form-button-group transparent-bg">
                                <button className="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-lg spinner-btn">{loading ? <><span className="spinner-border spinner-border-sm mr-05" role="status" aria-hidden="true"></span>Updating Profile</> : <>Update Profile</>}</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </ActionSheet>

                </form>

            </div>


        </div>
    </div>
);
}
export default AddFarm;
```